# Handling ComplexType In Web API MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

My project use Web API MVC 4 that it don't support complex type in OData query. Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solving above problem, use the following steps:

Install nuget package from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.

Remove any configuration from `Application_Start`.

Add `config.EnableQuerySupport()` to `WebApi.config`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Inheritance Support to OdataModelBuilder

Users can now define abstract entity types and entity types that derive from another entity type. OData doesn't support complex type inheritance.This commit only adds support in the ModelBuilder. Support for inheritance in the ODataConventionModelBuilder, ODataMediaTypeFormatter and Query support is still pending.

To install Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData, run the following command in the Package Manager Console :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Pre
```